# How to sort itertools.product in Python?

Tags: python

This is Product from itertools:

```
product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
```

But I wanna change to: --> `Ax Bx Cx Dx Ay By Cy Dy`
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the order of arguments and reverse tuples [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) yields. It'll probably be more efficient than sorting, since it doesn't need to build intermediate list.

```
from itertools import product

def reorder_product(*a):
    for tup in product(*a[::-1]):
        yield tup[::-1]
```

Example:

```
print(*[''.join(t) for t in reorder_product('ABCD', 'xy')])
# Output:
#     Ax Bx Cx Dx Ay By Cy Dy
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably be most efficient if you swap the order of the product and then simply reverse each of the yielded items:

```
def product_sorted_by_second(first, second):
    for item in itertools.product(second, first):
        yield item[::-1]
```

Of course, this is a horrible name for the function (since we aren't really sorting).

The advantage here is that you don't actually need to sort (which is an `O(NlogN)` processing step).  So this ends up being an `O(N)` algorithm  (where `N` is `len(first) * len(second)`)

Answer (score 0):

not overly elegant but it works:

```
for p in product( 'xy', 'ABCD'):
    print(''.join(reversed(p)))
```